# Faster alternatives to hFileSize to retrieve the size of a file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, filesystems, io

I am wondering how to get the size of a file in haskell with the least amount of overhead. Right now I have the following code:

```
getFileSize :: FilePath -> IO Integer
getFileSize x = do
handle <- openFile x ReadMode
size <- hFileSize handle
hClose handle
return size
```

This seems to be quite slow. I have stumbled across getFileStatus in System.Posix.Files but don't know how it works - at least I only get errors when playing around with it in ghci. Also, I am not sure if this would work on Windows (probably not).

So to reiterate: What is the best (and platform independent) approach to get the size of a file in Haskell?

Comment: Another problem with the above solution is that you can get the size of a file only when you can read it.

Comment: Exactly. I am a Haskell newbie and that was the first function I found. Of course I also run into all sorts of problems with permissions and stuff.

Comment: Using the file size for anything but displaying purposes is fragile.  If you get the file size and then use that for operating on the file there is no guarantee that the file with have the same size when you work on it.

Comment: btw, `getFileStatus "your_file_path" >>= print . fileSize` (from System.Posix.Files) should give you the size from GHCi (even if you don't have read permissions). Maybe worth trying recommended by Dan unix-compat (should it work on Windows).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want are indeed `getFileStatus` and `fileSize`, both from `System.Posix` (which will work just fine under Windows, if you use the [unix-compat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-compat) package instead of `unix`).  Usage is as follows, leaving error handling up to you:

```
getFileSize :: String -> IO Integer
getFileSize path = do
    stat <- getFileStatus path
    return $ fromIntegral (fileSize stat)
```

For what it's worth, and though I think it's less readable, you could shorten this form to:

```
getFileSize path = getFileStatus path >>= \s -> return $ fileSize s
```

Comment: You could also shorten it to `getFileSize path = fileSize <$> getFileStatus path` (replace `<$>` with `\`fmap\`` if you aren't using `Control.Applicative`; they're synonyms); with functorial composition defined by `let (f <.> g) x = f <$> g x in (<.>)`, this is `getFileSize = fileSize <.> getFileStatus`.  Both of these forms are, I think, just as readable, and have the nice bonus of being short.

Comment: Thanks @Antal S-Z.  You are right that the applicative syntax is much nicer looking.  On a related note, I would like to postulate a new theorem: On a long enough timeline, all Internet discussions related to Haskell invariably devolve into a round of golf.

Comment: @chomp Do you mind explaining why the System.Posix would work for windows as well? I thought Posix is a typical thing that don't work on windows unless you use cygwin or something.

Comment: @Tarrasch, I'm sure it depends on the (Haskell) library's implementation, but Microsoft's standard run-time library has for quite some time (since older versions of NT, IIRC) provided implementations of most (all?) of POSIX.1, which includes, among other things, `stat` and related utilities.  See for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you guys for all the background information. It is highly appreciated and I also upvoted everything I could. Great responses that help me out a lot!

Comment: Just tried this and on Windows 8 and "System.Posix" doesn't work.

Comment: `System.Posix` is in the `unix` package, whose [cabal file](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/unix.cabal) specifies `if os(windows): buildable: False`, so this should not work on Windows as the entire package doesn't build there (independent of whether Windows supports `stat`). The comment says `This package currently supports neither Cygwin nor MinGW`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if there is a better way. [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html) supplies its own wrapper to hFileSize:

```
getFileSize path = handle (\_ -> return Nothing) $
  bracket (openFile path ReadMode) hClose $ \h -> do
    size <- hFileSize h
    return (Just size)
```

It also notes that the [unix-compat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-compat) is available, which "provides portable implementations of parts of the unix package."

Comment: how about just `withFile path ReadMode hFileSize`

Answer (score 2):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.6.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v:getFileSize

```
getFileSize :: FilePath -> IO Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like System.Posix.Files doesn't work in Windows (except in Cygwin), have you tried unix-compat ?

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-compat-0.4.1.4/docs/System-PosixCompat-Files.html

This worked for me on my Windows 10 machine:

```
> cabal install unix-compat
Resolving dependencies...
... lots of output, plus I had to put Cygwin on my path to make it build ...
> ghci
Prelude> import System.PosixCompat.Files
Prelude System.PosixCompat.Files> getFileStatus ".bashrc">>= \s -> return $ fileSize s
5764
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import System.Posix.Files
import System.Posix.Types

getFileSize :: FilePath -> IO FileOffset
getFileSize path = fmap fileSize $ getFileStatus path
```