# How can I check if a text file is empty in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How can I check if a text file is empty in Haskell?

**I have already tried:**

```
main = do
       contents <- getContents
       if null contents then do
       putStrLn "File was empty"
       return()
       else do
       putStrLn "File was not empty"
       return
```

Comment: does [] == contents fix it?

Comment: null is a different thing

Comment: @Carbon [`null`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) is true iff the input list has no elements. As `String` is just `[Char]`, its usage here is perfectly correct.

Comment: `([]==)` and `null` in this case are equivalent. Usually `null` (or pattern matching) is preferred since it does not involve an `Eq` requirement.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is actually mostly in your formatting, not in your logic!

Whitespace matters in Haskell, see [this wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation). Following its rules, and fixing the minor typo in the last `return` statement (you need to return unit, `()`, like you did earlier):

```
main = do
   contents <- getContents
   if null contents then do
       putStrLn "File was empty"
       return ()
   else do
       putStrLn "File was not empty"
       return ()
```

And this should work perfectly. However, it's not reaally best practices - where you have the `do` block inside each part of the `if` expression you're constructing a new monadic action, which isn't necessary. Given that `putStrLn` returns an `IO ()` anyway, you can just do:

```
main = do
   contents <- getContents
   if null contents then
       putStrLn "File was empty"
   else
       putStrLn "File was not empty"
```

Bear in mind that the `if ... then x else y` expression returns a value of the same type as `x` and `y` are - here, `x` and `y` both have type `IO ()`, so the expression returns an `IO ()`, which is why it can be used inside this `do` block.

---

Note that this doesn't check if a file's empty, it checks if the standard input is empty: this is okay if you're piping input from a file into this program's stdin, but if you want to actually read from a file you should look into [`readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readFile) - and you'll barely need to change this program! Something like the following will do the trick:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Enter the file path:"
   path <- getLine
   contents <- readFile path
   if null contents ...
```

Comment: Since `if ... then ... else` is an expression, not a statement, this unnecessarily duplicates `putStrLn`. You can just write `putStrLn (if null contents then "File was empty" else "File was not empty")`. (You could even go crazy and write something like `putStrLn "File was " ++ (if null contents then "not" else "") ++ " empty"`.)

Comment: @chepner True, but I find the above way is easier to read - it keeps the lines short and the indentation follows the imperative style of the `do` block.

Answer (score 0):

@hnefatl's answer is fine, and is probably what you're looking for to get your original code working.  However, in case someone else stumbles across this question while trying to figure out how to check if a file is empty, a more advanced (but preferred) answer follows.

In "real" Haskell code, assuming you're trying to check the size of a plain file, you'd probably use `getFileStatus` and the helper function `fileSize` from `System.Posix`, as discussed in this question: [What is the best way to retrieve the size of a file in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620332/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrieve-the-size-of-a-file-in-haskell)

Specifically, a function like the following would work on Linux:

```
import System.Posix

isEmpty1 :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isEmpty1 fp = do
  stat <- getFileStatus fp
  return (fileSize stat == 0)
```

If you needed Windows compatibility, you could either install the `unix-compat` package which provides a cross-platform version of `getFileStatus`, or you could use `hFileSize` from `System.IO`:

```
import System.IO

isEmpty2 :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isEmpty2 fp = do
  sz <- withFile fp ReadMode hFileSize
  return (sz == 0)
```

The main advantage of `isEmpty1` above is that `getFileStatus` should be very efficient as it uses only one system call (a `stat` call). It would be the preferred approach if you had to check the size of lots of files.  The `isEmpty2` solution is okay, too, but it involves (at least) three system calls (`open`, then `fstat`, then `close`) and needs to open a file handle temporarily, which could be an issue if you were checking a lot of files in parallel or something.

Both will perform better than the `readFile` method as they don't cause a read of any file data.  In contrast, `readFile` needs to read at least one data block off the disk in order to determine that the resulting string is empty.

Thanks to Haskell's lazy I/O, it'll just do an initial read and won't have to read the whole file, but this leads to another odd quirk.  The way `readFile` is designed to open a file and lazily reads its contents, it turns out that the file is held open until the contents are completed read, and there's no other way to force the file to close without reading the complete contents!  Therefore, unless the file is short enough that it gets completely read by that initial read, the file handle will be held open indefinitely.  So, if you had a program that checked whether a whole bunch of text files were empty, if some of them larger than a single block, you'd probably end up running out of file handles.

In general, `readFile` shouldn't be used unless either (a) the whole file contents will be processed; or (b) the program will terminate soon after reading whatever partial contents it needs.

Comment: That's not a suggestion I would make quite so absolutely. `stat` is often incorrect for the in-memory pseudo-filesystems on Linux. For example, `0 <- fileSize <$> getFileStatus "/proc/cpuinfo"` and `0 <- withFile "/proc/cpuinfo" ReadMode hFileSize` but `False <- null <$> readFile "/proc/cpuinfo"`.