# Variable not in scope: getFileStatus turned into Failed to load interface for ‘System.Posix.Files.Common’ when importing the relevant package

Tags: haskell

I have the following code which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620332/faster-alternatives-to-hfilesize-to-retrieve-the-size-of-a-file-in-haskell), I want a function that will find the size of a file

```
getFileSize :: String -> IO Integer
getFileSize path = do
    stat <- getFileStatus path
    return $ fromIntegral (hFileSize stat)
```

This code gave the error 'Variable not in scope: getFileStatus'

I found that the variable is part of Posix, so I imported the files in the new code:

```
import System.IO
import System.Posix.Types
import System.Posix.Files.Common
import System.Posix.Error
import System.Posix.Internals


getFileSize :: String -> IO Integer
getFileSize path = do
    stat <- getFileStatus path
    return $ fromIntegral (hFileSize stat)
```

Now I get the error:
error:
Failed to load interface for ‘System.Posix.Files.Common’
it is a hidden module in the package ‘unix-2.7.2.1’
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [list of modules exposed by `unix-2.7.2.1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1), `System.Posix.Files.Common` is not listed. As the error message says, it’s a *hidden* module, internal to the `unix` package, so you can’t import it, and shouldn’t need to. The same goes for `System.Posix.Types` and `System.Posix.Internals`. The [`getFileStatus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:getFileStatus) function that you’re trying to use is exported by `System.Posix.Files`, so really you should only need that import.

You also seem to be trying to use [`hFileSize :: Handle -> IO Integer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hFileSize), but that operates on a `Handle`, not a `FileStatus`. You can use `hFileSize` if you want, but it takes a `Handle` instead of a `FilePath` / `String` like `getFileStatus` does, so you would just need to open a handle first, e.g.:

```
import System.IO (IOMode(..), hFileSize, withFile)

getFileSize :: FilePath -> IO Integer
getFileSize path = withFile path ReadMode hFileSize
```

If you still want to use the `unix` package for this, the function you want is [`fileSize :: FileStatus -> FileOffset`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-Files.html#v:fileSize) which is also exported from `System.Posix.Files`:

```
import System.Posix.Files (getFileStatus, fileSize)

getFileSize :: FilePath -> IO Integer
getFileSize path = do
    stat <- getFileStatus path
    return $ fromIntegral (fileSize stat)
```

Since all of the public modules are reexported by `System.Posix`, you could alternatively import everything from just that module. This is exactly what the original code you link did, so frankly I’m not sure why you didn’t just copy that.